# Minimize Repetitive Code?

Tags: objective-c, ios, optimization, repeat

I am trying to do a simple check in Objective C like this:

```
if ((spriteA.tag == 4 && spriteB.tag == 10)) {
}
```

However I am trying to accomplish **1** `if` check while achieving the following:

```
if ((spriteA.tag == 4 && spriteB.tag == 10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17)) {
}
```

Now I know I can use the `||` operator but that would make **1** `if` check many lines of code so it would look illegible. Now is there any organized way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Thanks!

Comment: `spriteA.tag == 4 && spriteB.tag >= 10 && spriteB.tag <= 17`?

Comment: I like @DanielFischer method best (I didn't know you could do that) because it doesn't involve the use of more lines of code (creation of NSSets)

Comment: It is tied to the allowable values forming a range, though. If that is not always the case, a set would be the way.

Comment: To be more specific `NSIndexSet` is probably what you want to look at if you are going that route

Comment: Also, it becomes more readable if you write a named method or function that describes what the test means. Something like `if (spritesWereProcessed(spriteA.tag, spriteB.tag)){...}` and then `BOOL spritesWereProcessed(int tagA, int tagB) { BOOL tagAProcessed = (tagA == kPassedTest); BOOL tagBProcessed = (tagB >= kTestMin && tagB <= kTestMax); return tagAProcessed && tagBProcessed;}` Just name everything and break out functionality that's complex into separate methods or functions. You have a bunch of ["magic numbers" (3rd definition)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach is probably to make a bit mask `int spriteBtags = (1 << 10) | (1 << 11) | (1 << 12) | ...;` and then test with `(1 << spriteB.tag) & spriteBtags`.  But note that this approach limits the values of spriteB.tag to the number of bits in an int or long.  And, of course, you have the long statement to create `spriteBtags`, but that's a one-time assignment.

Other languages like Pascal have bit sets, which makes this sort of thing more straight-forward.

(You could at least hide the complexity of the assignment statement by writing a varargs function: `int spriteBtags = createIntBitset(10,11,12,...17,-1);`)

Answer (score 1):

With enumeration-like values, a `switch` statement may be useful:

```
switch(spriteB.tag) {
case 4:
case 10:
case 12:
case 17:
case 42:
    ...
    break;
}
```